# Why is it always printing an extra line of "Annual Interest Rate”， how to solve this question?

Tags: java, loops

This is a mortgage calculator i am trying to implement, it allows the user to first enter the principal, the principal has to be a number betweem 1k and 1M, if it is not, the program will keep asking the user to input the right number, once the user has enter a correct number in that range, the programe will then ask the user to input the "Annual Interest Rate" which will be a number greater than 0 and less than or equal to 30, and once the user has enter the right "Annual Interest rate", the programe will ask the user to input period(yearly), keep asking if wrong input, and finally calculate the mortgage.

I am at the stage where i am trying to implement the Annual interest rate, (as shown in the image1) [iamge1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rreVH.png), but the output keep showing "Annual interest" twice, when it should show up once only and then continue, i have also tried another solution show in the image 2. [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8IrP.png), but idk how to handle with the yellow underline which indeicates that the if statement is always false. Can someone help me please, any hinters will be appriciated. Thank you.

[The image of image1 running.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFws6.png)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"Can someone help me please."* - If you want help, you **first** need to address the problems with your question that we have highlighted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following lines at line no. 20 and 21:

```
System.out.print("Annual Interest Rate: ");
AIR = input.nextFloat();
```

The above lines are redundant because you're reading the `AIR` value again inside the `while` loop at line no. 22.

Ideally, you should have a similar check for `period` as well to discard any negative values at least.

```
if (AIR > 0 && AIR <= 30) {
    while (period <= 0) {
        System.out.print("Period (Yearly): ");
        period = input.nextInt();
        if (period > 0) {
            // mortgage calculation
        } else
            System.out.println("Please enter a number greater than 0");
    }
} else ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked. BTW i will try and not post image of code again. Sry for the inconvenience. Thank you.